# Preview localized versions of strings-translated auto-layout XIBs

Tags: localization, interface-builder, autolayout, xib

I'm migrating away from one-XIB-per-locale to a single Base interface with Auto-Layout that is localized using `.strings` files.

How can I easily preview localized versions of my interface?

I'd like to see how my UI looks in German, Chinese and Arabic without having to change system-wide language preferences each time.

Selecting another language in Interface Builder's "Jump Bar" just shows me raw the `.strings` file source. IB's "Simulate Document" only shows me document in my current language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch application in a particular language [with an extra argument](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/250/9481):

```
Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo  -AppleLanguages '(de)'
```

However, that's not enough for Arabic, as it sets the language, but doesn't enable RTL layout:

```
app -AppleLanguages '(ar)' -NSForceRightToLeftWritingDirection YES -AppleTextDirection YES
```